# How to make free space in HDFS hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How we can make free space in HDFS if there is space issue.
Which files we can delete to make free space?

Thanks

Comment: offtopic. not a programming question. this is probably more DBA-related (and frankly, shouldn't a self-proclaimed hadoop expert already know this?)

Answer (score 1):

Compress your files wherever possible.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Data_Compression

The answer would seem shallow.  Put a little effort to find which compression would suit your needs.

Alternately you may store your files in binary format such as sequence or avro.

**Which files we can delete to make free space?**
Delete the ones which are no longer required by any jobs (such as MR, Hive,Pig, Spark, etc).

Comment: Also use replication factor judiciously.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Trash configuration enabled, you might have many files accumulated in '.Trash' directory (depending on your trash interval).
If so, you can try deleting the .Trash directory content.
Note:
Default trash directory is '/user/username/.Trash'